# Set variable if link is clicked for PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm really novice to PHP so sorry in advance if the question is really stupid. But thank you for paying attention to the post and helping!

[image: How the thing actually looks like]

```
<?php
   if ($tableResult = mysqli_query($conn,"show tables")){
        while($table = mysqli_fetch_array($tableResult)) {
            echo("<th>". "<a class = 'list_tables'>". $table[0] . "</a>" ."</th>");
      }
   }else{
        die("<b>"."No Table in Database!"."</b>");
      }
?>
```

If I want to set a variable for the link clicked, and the variable contains a value of the shown name, how do I do that?

If I'm wording it badly, please tell me, I will try to word it more clearly.

Thanks a lot for helping! It really means a lot to me

Comment: what kind of output do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome :)

If I'm reading this correctly, you want to pass which table was clicked to another page (or to the page you're on when it's reloaded). To do that, just set your `href` to something like this:

```
<a href='?clickedTable=$table[0]' class='list_tables'>". $table[0] . "</a>
```

Then on the php page, accept that variable like this:

```
$table = $_GET["clickedTable"];
```

Comment: Thank you, I got it fixed :D